# How to find average from a list of objects using JAVA streams

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, java-stream

I have two classes Bill and Charge as follows.

```
class Bill {

    private String id;
    private List<Charge> charges; 
    // Getters Setters Constructors etc..

}
```

```
class Charge{

    private String typeId;
    private double a;
    private double b;
    // Getters Setters Constructors etc..
}
```

```
List<Bill> bills  = new ArrayList<>();

Bill b1 = new Bill();
b1.setId("1");
List<Charge> charges = new ArrayList<>();
charges.add(new Charge("type-1",20,30));
charges.add(new Charge("type-2",30,30));
b1.setCharges(charges);

Bill b2 = new Bill();
b2.setId("2");
List<Charge> charges2 = new ArrayList<>();
charges2.add(new Charge("type-1",30,40));
charges2.add(new Charge("type-2",40,40));
b2.setCharges(charges2);
```

now i have a method,
this method should average Charges based on typeId and return only one Charge per typeId

```
public Bill average(List<Bill> bills){
...
}
```

i want this method to return a bill like following

```
Bill{
    id:null,
    charges:[
        {
            typeId:"type-1",
            a:25,
            b:35
        },
        {
            typeId:"type-2",
            a:35,
            b:35
        }
    ]
}
```

this can be achieved using for or forEach loops but I am looking to resolve this Streams api

Comment: _this can be achieved using for or forEach loops_ share it, please.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static Bill average(List<Bill> bills) {
    final List<Charge> charges = bills.stream()
            .flatMap(x -> x.getCharges().stream())
            .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                    Collectors.groupingBy(
                            Charge::getTypeId,
                            billInfoToAverage()
                    ),
                    x -> new ArrayList<>(x.values())
            ));
    return new Bill(null, charges);
}


public static Collector<Charge, BillInfoAccumulator, Charge> billInfoToAverage() {
    return Collector.of(
            BillInfoAccumulator::new,
            BillInfoAccumulator::add,
            BillInfoAccumulator::combine,
            BillInfoAccumulator::average
    );
}


class BillInfoAccumulator {
    private String typeId;
    private final DoubleSummaryStatistics aStats = new DoubleSummaryStatistics();
    private final DoubleSummaryStatistics bStats = new DoubleSummaryStatistics();

    public void add(Charge charge) {
        typeId = charge.getTypeId();
        aStats.accept(charge.getA());
        bStats.accept(charge.getB());
    }

    public BillInfoAccumulator combine(BillInfoAccumulator accumulator) {
        aStats.combine(accumulator.aStats);
        bStats.combine(accumulator.bStats);
        return this;
    }

    public Charge average() {
        return new Charge(typeId, aStats.getAverage(), bStats.getAverage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work, though it does not look too beautful:

```
public Bill average(List<Bill> bills) {
    List<Charge> avgCharges = bills.stream().flatMap(b -> b.getCharges().stream())
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Charge::getTypeId))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> {
            double avgA = x.getValue().stream().mapToDouble(Charge::getA).average().getAsDouble();
            double avgB = x.getValue().stream().mapToDouble(Charge::getB).average().getAsDouble();
            return new Charge(x.getKey(), avgA, avgB);
        }, Map.Entry::getValue))
        .keySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toList());

    return new Bill("avgCharges", avgCharges);
}
```

Testing snippet:

```
Bill avg = average(Arrays.asList(b1, b2));

avg.getCharges().stream()
.forEach(c -> System.out.println(c.getTypeId() + "-> a=" + c.getA() + ", b=" + c.getB()));
```

provides the following output:

```
type-1-> a=25.0, b=35.0
type-2-> a=35.0, b=35.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public Bill average(List<Bill> bills) {
    final List<Charge> charges = bills.stream()
            .flatMap(x -> x.getCharges().stream())
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Charge::getTypeId))
            .entrySet().stream()
            .map(x -> new Charge(
                    x.getKey(),
                    x.getValue().stream().mapToDouble(Charge::getA).average().getAsDouble(),
                    x.getValue().stream().mapToDouble(Charge::getB).average().getAsDouble()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    return new Bill(null, charges);
}
```

Or

```
public Bill average(List<Bill> bills) {
    return bills.stream()
            .flatMap(x -> x.getCharges().stream())
            .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.groupingBy(Charge::getTypeId),
                    x -> {
                        final List<Charge> charges = x.entrySet().stream()
                                .map(y -> new Charge(
                                        y.getKey(),
                                        y.getValue().stream().mapToDouble(Charge::getA).average().getAsDouble(),
                                        y.getValue().stream().mapToDouble(Charge::getB).average().getAsDouble()))
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
                        return new Bill(null, charges);
                    }));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A very **naive and simple** solution. Of course **the number of operations can be reduced to half** but this makes it simpler to understand.

1. Collect charges from each bills according to types. Since each bill has list of charges, we need to use `flatMap` for extracting charges and collecting them all into one list and `filter` to filter by type.
2. Find average of a and b according to type
3. Create a new Bill object and return the same

   ```
       List<Charge> t1Charges = bills.stream()
                                     .flatMap(b -> b.charges.stream())
                                     .filter(c -> c.typeId == "type-1")
                                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
       List<Charge> t2Charges = bills.stream()
                                     .flatMap(b -> b.charges.stream())
                                     .filter(c -> c.typeId == "type-2")
                                     .collect(Collectors.toList());

       Double t1a = t1Charges.stream()
                             .mapToDouble(x -> x.a)
                             .average()
                             .getAsDouble();
       Double t1b = t1Charges.stream()
                             .mapToDouble(x -> x.b)
                             .average()
                             .getAsDouble();

       final Double t2a = t2Charges.stream()
                                   .mapToDouble(x -> x.a)
                                   .average()
                                   .getAsDouble();
       final Double t2b = t2Charges.stream()
                                   .mapToDouble(x -> x.b)
                                   .average()
                                   .getAsDouble();

       final Bill av = new Bill();
       av.charges.add(new Charge("type-1",t1a,t1b));
       av.charges.add(new Charge("type-2",t2a,t2b));

       return av;
   ```